# Why does the Identity v2 naming schema differ between EF and AspNet?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-identity-2, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I wonder if anyone out there can help me with the following problem...

I have a created a EF code first database (sqlexpress) that uses Identity v2   -I can see within that database all my models, including the Identity related tables starting with Identity* (ie. IdentityUserClaims, IdentityUserLogins, IdentityUserRoles IdentityRoles & IdentityUsers).

I then create a brand new MVC project as well as adding the same connection string. When I register a new user -for some reason it goes off and creates Identity v2 tables starting with AspNet* (ie. AspNetUserClaims, AspNetUserLogins, AspNetUserRoles AspNetRoles & AspNetUsers).

[I am using... EF 6.1.1, Identity 2.1, MVC 5.2]

Why does the Identity naming schema differ between EF and AspNet ?  how do I make MVC use the EF schema  Identity* ?

Answer (score 0):

You can override table names by `[Table("MyUsers")]`  attribute on top of your classes:

```
[Table("WhateverILikeUsers")]
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
}
```

Or you can rename tables in DbContext:

```
public class MyContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    // other stuff

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().ToTable("HelloIdentity");
    }
}
```